# How can I fix the steel moment resisting frame modeling problem in notepad++ (tcl lang. /OpenSEES)?

Tags: tcl, opensees

I want to model rotational spring for beams in my model in notepad++ (I used tcl lang. in notepad++ editor so I can find lines of errors and open brackets etc., a bit easier) like the picture (MRF) that I add, but without considering RBS. I wrote the code that I paste its lines below but unfortunately, it has an error (warning domain). I did lots of trial and error but I couldn't fix it. Can anyone please help me? (j=floors i=piers)
(because my model is big (10 stories), I want to model it on a programming base)

```
for {set j 1} {$j <= $nFlrs} {incr j} {
    
    for {set i 1} {$i <= $nBays} {incr i} { 
        set ID1 [expr 4*1000+($i*10+$j)*10+1]
        set nodeR1 [expr ($i*10+$j)*100+5]
        set nodeC1 [expr ($i*10+$j)*10+1]
    }   
    for {set i 1} {$i <= $nBays+1} {incr i} {
        set ID2 [expr 4*1000+($i*10+$j)*10+2]
        set nodeR2 [expr (($i+1)*10+$j)*100+10]
        set nodeC2 [expr (($i+1)*10+$j)*10+2]
    }
}
    uniaxialMaterial Bilin $ID1 $ke $alfah $alfah $my -$my $lambda 0\
        0 0 1 0 0 0 $tetap $tetap $tetapc $tetapc 0 0 $tetau $tetau 1 1 $nFactor
    uniaxialMaterial Bilin $ID2 $ke $alfah $alfah $my -$my $lambda 0\
        0 0 1 0 0 0 $tetap $tetap $tetapc $tetapc 0 0 $tetau $tetau 1 1 $nFactor
    
    # define beam springs   
    element zeroLength $ID1 $nodeR1 $nodeC1 -mat $ID1 -dir 6
    element zeroLength $ID2 $nodeR2 $nodeC2 -mat $ID2 -dir 6

    #Constrain the translational DOF with a multi-point constraint
    #                   retained constrained DOF_1 DOF_2 ... DOF_n
           equalDOF    $nodeR1     $nodeC1     1     2
           equalDOF    $nodeR2     $nodeC2     1     2
}
incr ID1
incr ID2
```

[image: Steel moment resisting frame with panel zone and plastic hinge in beams]

```
warning: WARNING Domain::addElement - In element 4401
 no Node 4005 exists in the domain
```

Comment: How is this related to Notepad++ ?

Comment: Please re-format your question.  You've got parts of it in markdown and other parts in regular text.  Very confusing.

Comment: This smells like homework. Do you need nested loops, where the uniaxialMaterial command appears in the body of the inner-most loop?

Comment: Also, the 2nd argument to `for`, the condition, is already handled as an arithmetic expression, so you don't need the `expr` command: `{$i <= [expr $nBays+1]}` -> `{$i <= $nBays + 1}`

Comment: Excuse me. Actually, it is my first question in StackOverflow. I became a little confused while I was writing my request! Is it now clear?

Comment: No, the formatting is still not readable.  is there supposed to be just a single block of code?

Comment: @ChrisHeithoff , I think now the formatting is Ok. hope you can help me.

Comment: It sounds like you've asked the OpenSees code to use something that doesn't exist by passing in an ID that doesn't correspond to anything. The "fix" is "don't do that", but that's probably best done by moving element generation into the loop (instead of doing what appears to be a bunch of useless variable setting). Tcl, like most languages, doesn't care about indentation, but rather about where your `{` braces `}` are.

Comment: As you've indented it, the brace in the first column half way through your code looks suspicious.

Comment: @Donal, Could you please explain more about how should I use a loop for defining nodes and also zerolength element ID? I'm a bit amateur in programming!

Answer (score 0):

The big problem you've got is that you are not doing the making of the entities that you'll be simulating in the loops; you loop, but you don't do anything useful with that.

Now, I really don't know OpenSees, but here's a guess as to how you might go about fixing things. Or at least the first step.

```
for {set j 1} {$j <= $nFlrs} {incr j} {
    for {set i 1} {$i <= $nBays} {incr i} { 
        set ID1 [expr 4*1000+($i*10+$j)*10+1]
        set nodeR1 [expr ($i*10+$j)*100+5]
        set nodeC1 [expr ($i*10+$j)*10+1]

        uniaxialMaterial Bilin $ID1 $ke $alfah $alfah $my -$my $lambda 0\
            0 0 1 0 0 0 $tetap $tetap $tetapc $tetapc 0 0 $tetau $tetau 1 1 $nFactor
        element zeroLength $ID1 $nodeR1 $nodeC1 -mat $ID1 -dir 6
        equalDOF    $nodeR1     $nodeC1     1     2
    }   
    for {set i 1} {$i <= $nBays+1} {incr i} {
        set ID2 [expr 4*1000+($i*10+$j)*10+2]
        set nodeR2 [expr (($i+1)*10+$j)*100+10]
        set nodeC2 [expr (($i+1)*10+$j)*10+2]

        uniaxialMaterial Bilin $ID2 $ke $alfah $alfah $my -$my $lambda 0\
            0 0 1 0 0 0 $tetap $tetap $tetapc $tetapc 0 0 $tetau $tetau 1 1 $nFactor
        element zeroLength $ID2 $nodeR2 $nodeC2 -mat $ID2 -dir 6
        equalDOF    $nodeR2     $nodeC2     1     2
    }
}
```

All I have done here is move code that was *after* the loops to *inside* the loops (and deleted a few junk lines). I do not know that what's written now is correct, but it looks much more likely to be so. In particular, the places where the variables are written are next to where they are used, which is probably a good idea.

---

The next stage of cleaning up this code is to introduce a helper procedure.

```
# I'm terrible at naming things!
proc makeThing {id nodeR nodeC} {
    global ke alfah my lambda tetap tetapc tetau nFactor

    uniaxialMaterial Bilin $id $ke $alfah $alfah $my -$my $lambda 0\
        0 0 1 0 0 0 $tetap $tetap $tetapc $tetapc 0 0 $tetau $tetau 1 1 $nFactor
    element zeroLength $id $nodeR $nodeC -mat $id -dir 6
    equalDOF    $nodeR     $nodeC     1     2
}

for {set j 1} {$j <= $nFlrs} {incr j} {
    for {set i 1} {$i <= $nBays} {incr i} { 
        # I'm also going to put the expressions in braces, for performance
        # It gives the expression compiler a chance to do something sensible!
        set ID1    [expr { 4*1000+($i*10+$j)*10+1 }]
        set nodeR1 [expr { ($i*10+$j)*100+5 }]
        set nodeC1 [expr { ($i*10+$j)*10+1 }]

        makeThing $ID1 $nodeR1 $nodeC1
    }   
    for {set i 1} {$i <= $nBays+1} {incr i} {
        set ID2    [expr { 4*1000+($i*10+$j)*10+2 }]
        set nodeR2 [expr { (($i+1)*10+$j)*100+10 }]
        set nodeC2 [expr { (($i+1)*10+$j)*10+2 }]

        makeThing $ID2 $nodeR2 $nodeC2
    }
}
```

The point of the procedure is that you have one place where you try to do things right (test it until it works) and then you can effectively stamp out all the places where you need that little pattern by just calling the procedure.

Comment: thank you very much for your kindness and help. At least you showed me the right way to do programming.